# Datasheet view added programatically missing from view selector

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, csom, view, datasheet

I am adding a new view to a list using CSOM (`ViewTypeKind` = `Grid`).

The same code works perfectly for other types of views.

For datasheet views, although they are added and they function properly, they are only available in the ribbon dropdown, not in the page <s>context menu</s> view selector.

[image]

The fact that other people are experiencing this makes me suspect of an issue in the API but perhaps there is something we can do to overcome this.

Adding the view manually through the UI works fine.

Similar thread:

[List views of type Datasheet created in CSOM do not appear in the list's 'view selector'](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/db5abb51-0867-4d24-af81-29f844d66cde/list-views-of-type-datasheet-created-in-csom-do-not-appear-in-the-lists-view-selector)

About the View Selector (aka **ClientPivotControl**):

[List View Web part not showing all available views for list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126234/list-view-web-part-not-showing-all-available-views-for-list)

**EDIT:**

Here's a basic example in case anyone wants to give it a try.

BTW, it appears that this issue is **not limited to CSOM**. It happens the same when adding datasheet views from the **server side**.

```
param(
    $webUrl = "http://yourwebsite",
    $listTitle = "yourlisttitle",
    $viewTitle = "datasheet-test"
)

$web = get-spweb $webUrl
$list = $web.Lists[$listTitle]
$view = $list.Views.Add($viewTitle, "Name", "", 50, $true, $false, "GRID", $false)
```

Comment: What do u mean by contextual menu?

Comment: in every list view/page there is a control next to the search box called ms-pivotControl. this control is responsible for displaying *some* of the views in that area and there is a 3 dot context menu to pick more views. this is done by some scripts in clienttemplates.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So time is running out and I don't see any solution for this.

User gautam pointed me in the right direction, which is why I am giving him the bounty, but I want to post the actual answer myself.

This is clearly a bug in the **SP2013** version of the **view selector** functionality, which is setup in the actual **webpart**, not the view.

I'd also like to point out that this issue is not limited to **SSOM** or **CSOM**, it happens in both and it also happens in various types of views, such as **Datasheet** and **Calendar**, probably others.

The workaround is to trigger an update on the `DisableViewSelectorMenu` webpart property, which can be achieved by manually editing the view webpart through the user interface, or programatically updating the property and the webpart, as shown below.

```
public void FixWebPartViewSelector(ClientContext context, string listTitle, string viewFileName)
{
    Web web = context.Web;
    List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
    context.Load(list, l => l.RootFolder);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    string pageUrl = list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Forms/" + viewFileName;

    Console.WriteLine("Fixing view selector in: " + pageUrl);

    File file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(pageUrl);
    PersonalizationScope scope = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared;
    LimitedWebPartManager wpm = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(scope);

    context.Load(wpm);
    context.Load(wpm.WebParts);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    int numWebparts = wpm.WebParts.Count;

    Console.WriteLine("Found " + numWebparts + " webparts!");
    if(numWebparts == 1)
    {
        WebPartDefinition wpd = wpm.WebParts[0];
        WebPart wp = wpd.WebPart;

        //PrintWebpartProperties(context, wp);

        //update view selector
        wp.Properties["DisableViewSelectorMenu"] = false;

        //commit
        wpd.SaveWebPartChanges();
        context.ExecuteQuery();
    }    
}
```

**USAGE:**

```
FixWebPartViewSelector(context, "Documents", "AllItems.aspx");
```

See also

[(Calendar) list views disappear from view selector menu of list view webpart](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88841/calendar-list-views-disappear-from-view-selector-menu-of-list-view-webpart)

[Programmatically created calendar view does not appear on view selector menu](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6911c166-1198-4337-8665-964f0275c830/programmatically-created-calendar-view-does-not-appear-on-view-selector-menu?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, i tried the below mentioned code and it works. It's created in CSOM.

```
List taskList = currentWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("Tasks");

                // Get all the view  
                //for the custom list  
                ViewCollection viewColl = taskList.Views;

                // Specify the columns that should be displayed
                string[] viewFields = { "ID", "LinkTitle", "StartDate", "DueDate", "AssignedTo", "Status", "Body" };

                // Specifies the properties used to create a new list view    

                ViewCreationInformation creationInfo = new ViewCreationInformation();
                creationInfo.Title = "All my custom Tasks";
                creationInfo.RowLimit = 30;
                creationInfo.ViewFields = viewFields;
                creationInfo.ViewTypeKind = ViewType.Grid;
                creationInfo.SetAsDefaultView = false;
                viewColl.Add(creationInfo);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
```

[image]

Comment: sure it appears in view selector (while a different view is open)? what specs/versions?

Comment: @TiagoDuarte Yes, this is production ready code. The csom dll version number is 16.0.2617.1200

Comment: it's possible that it works in Office 365. but this question is specific for 2013

Comment: Yep, looks like 2013 specific issue. Hopefully might get fixed in future updates. However , i was able to get it working after a one time activity. I clicked on edit page > edit webpart > disable view selector menu(tick checkbox) > OK. Then again edit webpart > disable view selector menu > uncheck the checkbox > Ok > Save page. After doing this, i was able to get it working.

Comment: check above screenshot for "Disable view selector menu".

Comment: no luck. view still doesnt appear in selector when *another* view is selected. obviously it displays in the selector if the view itself it the one active

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46426/discussion-between-gautam-and-tiago-duarte).

Comment: Yes, all other views have dedicated pages for example , in task view - completed.aspx , gantt.aspx etc and each of them have webpart. So webpart needs to be edited on every "views" page.
Definitely there is some issue with SharePoint here, but looks like no other option than to edit each view page of list/doclib and modifying it.

Comment: I'm working with a document library, not really a custom/tasks list. but I will give this another go. if it works, hopefully it's something that can be automated. can't go through hundreds of sites manually :p

Answer (score 2):

This solution works for me with update `ViewTypeKind` like `creationInfo.ViewTypeKind = ViewType.Grid | ViewType.Html;` using CSOM

```
     List taskList = currentWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");

        // Get all the view  
        //for the custom list  
        ViewCollection viewColl = taskList.Views;

        // Specify the columns that should be displayed
        string[] viewFields = { "ID", "LinkFilename", "Title", "Editor" };

        // Specifies the properties used to create a new list view    

        ViewCreationInformation creationInfo = new 
        ViewCreationInformation();
        creationInfo.Title = "DataSheet by Selva";
        creationInfo.RowLimit = 30;
        creationInfo.ViewFields = viewFields;
        creationInfo.ViewTypeKind = **ViewType.Grid | ViewType.Html;**
        creationInfo.SetAsDefaultView = false;
        viewColl.Add(creationInfo);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks @MHeld for updated with right format. Hereafter I will take care.